# applying custom function in R pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data similar to below. **ppt** = participant number, **correct** = whether the ppt chose correctly or not (1 = correct, 0 = incorrect), and **key_rt** is participant reaction time when making their choice

```
data <- data.frame(ppt = rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 5),
                   correct = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
                   key_rt = runif(15))
```

And I have a function that I would like to apply to this data. It requires the percentage of correct responses (Pc), mean reaction time (MRT), and variance of reaction time (VRT).

However, when I load this function into my global environment, and then try to apply this to my data by running the code below, I receive the following error message: *"Error in EZ(Pc, VRT, MRT) : object 'Pc' not found"*.

```
df <- data %>%
  group_by(ppt) %>%
  summarise(Pc = mean(correct),
            VRT = var(key_rt[correct==1]),
            MRT = mean(key_rt[correct==1])) %>% 
  mapply(FUN = EZ(Pc, VRT, MRT))
```

I wondered if this was because of the pipes that I have used. Even though Pc is calculated before the EZ function is applied, it seems that the function cannot recognise this Pc that is required for the function to work.

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: The issue is syntactic. `mapply` expects a *function*. But you’re not passing a function to it, you’re passing it the *result* of *invoking* a function (and in addition that function invocation fails because it can’t be invoked in this context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the output in a list for each `ppt` and use `unnest_wider` to get separate columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  group_by(ppt) %>%
  summarise(Pc = mean(correct),
            VRT = var(key_rt[correct==1]),
            MRT = mean(key_rt[correct==1]), 
            out = list(EZ(Pc, VRT, MRT, n()))) %>%
  unnest_wider(out)

#    ppt    Pc    VRT   MRT      v     a     Ter
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1   0.6 0.0399 0.500  0.407 0.997  0.255 
#2     2   1   0.130  0.391  1.36  1.61  -0.0840
#3     3   0.4 0.282  0.574 -0.249 1.63  -0.0775
```

I am using `n = n()` indicating number of rows in the group. I am guessing this is what it is supposed to mean here.

Comment: This code achieved the desired outcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `mutate` instead of `mapply`. You also need to fix the default value of your parameter `n`: `lenght(correct)` doesn’t work, since there’s no variable `correct` in scope. I have to guess here, but I think `n = length(Pc)` should work.

Note that, unlike Ronak’s solution, this will vectorise over the entire data.frame; that is, the function `EZ` will be called *once* in your example, and the arguments will be *column vectors* of length 3. Whereas in Ronak’s example the function will be called *three times* (once per group), and each time its arguments will be just a single value. — Based on the information you’ve provided I don’t know which of the two solutions is correct, both are plausible without understanding what `EZ` is supposed to compute.